# Want to receive argument from user and put them on function

Tags: encryption, user-input, command-line-arguments, public-key-encryption, caesar-cipher

I want to get arguments from user and use them in function, but the types are different.

**Note**: a comment is there in bottom of code that is correctly work
but I want to get arguments directly

Thanks for your help

```
from string import ascii_letters

def encrypt(string , key):
    alpha = ascii_letters
    result = ''

    for ch in string : 
        if ch not in alpha :
            result += ch
        else :
            new_key = (alpha.index(ch) + key.str() ) % len(alpha)
            result += alpha[new_key]
    return result

def decrypt(string , key):
    key *= -1
    return encrypt(string , key)
state = ''
print("please enter 'e' to encrpyt & type 'd' to decrpyt :...")
state = input()

if state == 'e' : 
    print("please enter the str that you want to encrypt :... ")
    c_str1 = input()
    print("\nplease enter the key that shifts strings(e.x. 1 to 52):... ")
    c_in1=input()
    encrypt(c_str1, c_in1)

elif state == 'd':
    print("please enter the str that you want to decrypt :... ")
    c_str= input('')
    print("\nplease enter the key (e.x. 1 to 52):... ")
    c_in = input()
    decrypt(c_str, c_in )
   
# print(decrypt('amir',4))
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure what your question is , here my attempt at making your code run,
not sure runs as you expected:

```
from string import ascii_letters

def encrypt(string , key):
    result = ''
    alpha = ascii_letters
    for ch in string : 
        if ch not in alpha :
            result += ch
        else :
            new_key = (alpha.index(ch) + int(key))  % len(alpha)
            
            result += alpha[new_key]
    return result

def decrypt(string , key):
    key *= -1
    return encrypt(string , key)


state = ''
print("please enter 'e' to encrpyt & type 'd' to decrpyt :...")
state = input()

if state == 'e' : 
    print("please enter the str that you want to encrypt :... ")
    c_str1 = input()
    print("\nplease enter the key that shifts strings(e.x. 1 to 52):... ")
    c_in1 = input()
    print(encrypt(c_str1, c_in1))

elif state == 'd':
    print("please enter the str that you want to decrypt :... ")
    c_str = input()
    print("\nplease enter the key (e.x. 1 to 52):... ")
    c_in = int(input())
    print(decrypt(c_str, c_in ))
```